# Send Azure DevOps Pipeline Details to SIEM

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, azure-devops

I want to add pipeline details(status, id, who triggered it) to my SIEM solution. For that, can you suggest me how to get that information.

Some rough Ideas

1. Invoke a lambda from Pipeline and supply pipeline related information through SNS

If the above is possible, can you tell me how. I couldn't find a way to do it dynamically for all pipelines. I don't want to hardcore Project and Organization details.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very familiar with SIEM, but for azure devops pipelines, you can get their detailed information programmatically by REST APIs.

You can use [Pipelines - Get](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/get?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) to get information about pipeline's status, id, who triggered it and so on.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

You can click [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) for more resources of Azure DevOps Pipelines REST APIs.

It uses [PAT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/organizations/accounts/use-personal-access-tokens-to-authenticate?view=azure-devops&tabs=preview-page) or OAuth2 as the authentication method and returns information as JSON.

**Updates:**

Here is a REST API [Pipelines - List](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/pipelines/list?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0) that can get a list of pipelines in a project.

```
GET https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines?api-version=6.0-preview.1
```

Comment: How do you plan to get the pipelineID? This would only work for one pipeline, where we use hardcoded values.

Comment: @Dushyant Bhardwaj I have updated my answer and hope it can help.

Comment: Thanks for it. But these will be useful if we want to run the check outside of pipeline. If we want to do the same while pipeline runs and send the data to SIEM we can use 
"Pre-Defined Variables" They can give us a lot of information about Pipeline. I am using these for now. API's are also a good option. Thanks for your help :)